# Webapp to search Google using React

Tags: html, reactjs, google-chrome, web, search-engine

I'm trying to make a web-application using React that searches over the web. My requirements are I need to make a SPA that also has back, refresh and forward button ( cannot use browser's default buttons ). I tried using [Programmable Search Engine](https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/) from Google but it won't work along with the iframe tag. Any suggestions/approaches will be helpful. Thank you!